# Methods to build tight-binding models for realistic materials

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, one-topic-per-answer, tight-binding, wannier90

I am aware that a standard way to build tight-binding models for realistic crystalline systems is by using the Maximally-localized Wannier Functions (MLWFs) as implemented in the Wannier90 Fortran code.

My question is: what are the other methods used today in building tight-binding models for crystalline systems? I am interested in building minimal models (e.g. using 2 x 2 or 4 x 4 Bloch Hamiltonians, say). Can one use Wannier90 for this calculation? are there other better approaches?

My main goal is to build minimal tight-binding models to study topological systems (e.g. topological insulators, superconductors etc.). I also would like to be able to build minimal tight-binding models for strongly-correlated system. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not an expert, but Wannier90 can certainly be used for creating tight-binding Hamiltonians for the study of topological properties, that's what [z2pack](https://z2pack.greschd.ch/en/latest/) does. If you have questions, you may want to reach out to the author Dominik Gresch, he is a nice guy.

Comment: Thanks, my question is more general. I'd like to know if there's a reference that summarizes the available methods that exist for building tight-binding models on top of the first principles calculations

Comment: dbrane, it's possible that @leopold.talirz did not see your response because not only was it 10 days after Leopold's comment, but you did not use the @ symbol to ping the username. Since you haven't signed in for 5 months we'll close this question as "abandoned" (assuming that you found an answer or are no longer interested), but the question can be reopened if you come back, or if someone wants to write an answer (just leave a comment and we can reopen it).